# Since VFRC feature in VMware is now end of lifed, what can I replace it with?

Tags: vmware-esxi, cache, ssd, nvme

Now that VFRC (vflash read cache) is end of lifed in Vsphere 7, does anyone have suggestions on what I could replace it with. Looks like there is only Infinio and Virtunet in the market now, has anyone tried these or any others?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. Ask VMware or delay your vSphere upgrade until you can provision hardware that can meet your workload demands.

What is your backend storage solution?

VFRC was a weak stopgap that came with some baggage. It may have been a good idea 6 years ago, but I've had to disable it in every environment for stability reasons or on the recommendation of support.